# Greek Letters in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to print Greek letters on an HTML5 canvas?  I've tried using the html entity name and number, like this

```
canvas2.cx.fillText("&xi;", 50, 50);
```

and

```
canvas2.cx.fillText("&#958;", 50, 50);
```

but it just prints it out literally because the canvas does not know to interpret these symbols.

Comment: That's because a `<script>` block or an external script file is interpreted as literal data, rather than expanding entities (as is usual in HTML text nodes and attribute values). Had this been XHTML, your inline script wouldn't have been special, and you could have used entities, although you would have had to HTML encode your ampersands and less than signs as well, which is awkward.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas: Degree Symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671841/html5-canvas-degree-symbol)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply use UTF-8.

You don't have to escape chars to write them in HTML or Canvas.

Use the correct header in your document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
```

Comment: For HTML5 you can simply write [`<meta charset="utf-8">`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/which-one-to-use-meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type).

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks, I didn't knew that (I checked the norm, you're right).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to restrict your JavaScript source to ASCII, but still include non-ASCII characters in a string, you can use a Unicode escape sequence: (small xi's codepoint is U+03BE):

```
canvas2.cx.fillText("\u03be", 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like `α` and `β`? If you're using UTF-8, you may be able to just type the character literals. example:

```
canvas2.cx.fillText("α", 50, 50);
```